# python : encode using string-escape to get the correct quotes

Tags: python, escaping, encode

I want to encode my string :

```
x="print 'Hello.\nI\'m a robot from district 09'"
x=x.encode('string-escape')
print x

# Result: print \'Hello.\nI\'m a robot from district 09\'
```

But that's not the result i'm expecting. I want something like :

```
# Result: print 'Hello.\nI\'m a robot from district 09'
```

How to get that result ? so when i execute it using 'exec x' i will get this :

```
exec x
# Result: 
Hello.
I'm a robot from district 09
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [repr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr)

```
x="print 'Hello.\nI\'m a robot from district 09'"
print repr(x)

# Result: 'Hello.\nI\'m a robot from district 09'
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comment this method misses out the ' in the I'm
Printing raw string can be simply achieved using 'r'. See the example below. I have this time confirmed the result myself.

```
x= r"print 'Hello, \nI\'m a robot from district 09'"
print x

#result: print 'Hello, \nI\'m a robot from district 09'
```

**Edit2** : You can't turn an existing string "raw". The r prefix on literals is understood by the parser; it tells it to ignore escape sequences in the string. However, once a string literal has been parsed, there's no difference between a raw string and a "regular" one. If you have a string that contains a newline, for instance, there's no way to tell at runtime whether that newline came from the escape sequence \n or from a string like "\next". The actual string object constructed from any of those methods looks the same.

So any attempts to use string-encode/string-escape and repr will fail for the usage you are expecting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but still wrong result : "print 'Hello.\nI'm a robot from district 09'" . The " \' " in -i'm- is missing.

Comment: @andio Please see the edit. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: Hi, yes i've tried that also. the 'r' is working only if i can set the x by myself. But if the x is  variable which is entered by other user (using text input interface). How can than embed that 'r' to that variable ? so the goal is : user enter the command in the text input. Then i provide button which than i can use 'exec ' command to run it.

Comment: actually that r'mystring' is perfect solution. But if someone give me the string variable VAR, how can i embed it to be semething like : rVAR. Seems there's no way i can do that